# How to mock the results of BigQueryIO.read for unit testing?

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-beam-io

I have an Apache Beam pipeline that reads data from BigQuery using a query that joins multiple tables.
I want to test the entire pipeline locally using mock data (i.e. without connecting to BigQuery).
Can I do this using `.withTestServices(fakeBigQueryServices)`? I could not find any relevant examples. Has anyone tried this approach or has suggestions on how this can be done?

```
String query = "Select o.*, p.name from Order o, Product p where o.product_id = p.id and o.created_on = '20220210'"
pipeline.apply("read data", BigQueryIO.read(input -> new OrderMapper().mapRow(input.getRecord()))
                                      .withCoder(SerializableCoder.of(Order.class))
                                      .fromQuery(query)
                                      .withoutValidation())
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be find mockup bigquery services on apache beam.

Asides from that, there are options available within Apache beam that you can use to mimic a database and build your own function that can behave in a similar way. I will share an updated example *[Reading from a SQLite database](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/examples/notebooks/tour-of-beam/reading-and-writing-data.ipynb)* from the beam project for visibility:

**1. Install these libraries**

```
!pip install --upgrade apache-beam
!pip install --upgrade httplib2==0.20.0
# Note you might encounter issues with the library installation reinstall if necessary.
```

**2. Create a mockup database (using sqlite3)**

```
import sqlite3

database_file = "moon-phases.db" #@param {type:"string"}

with sqlite3.connect(database_file) as db:
  cursor = db.cursor()

  # Create the moon_phases table.
  cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS moon_phases (
      id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
      phase_emoji TEXT NOT NULL,
      peak_datetime DATETIME NOT NULL,
      phase TEXT NOT NULL)''')

  # Truncate the table if it's already populated.
  cursor.execute('DELETE FROM moon_phases')

  # Insert some sample data.
  insert_moon_phase = 'INSERT INTO moon_phases(phase_emoji, peak_datetime, phase) VALUES(?, ?, ?)'
  cursor.execute(insert_moon_phase, ('', '2017-12-03 15:47:00', 'Full Moon'))
  cursor.execute(insert_moon_phase, ('', '2017-12-10 07:51:00', 'Last Quarter'))
  cursor.execute(insert_moon_phase, ('', '2017-12-18 06:30:00', 'New Moon'))
  cursor.execute(insert_moon_phase, ('', '2017-12-26 09:20:00', 'First Quarter'))
  cursor.execute(insert_moon_phase, ('', '2018-01-02 02:24:00', 'Full Moon'))
  cursor.execute(insert_moon_phase, ('', '2018-01-08 22:25:00', 'Last Quarter'))
  cursor.execute(insert_moon_phase, ('', '2018-01-17 02:17:00', 'New Moon'))
  cursor.execute(insert_moon_phase, ('', '2018-01-24 22:20:00', 'First Quarter'))
  cursor.execute(insert_moon_phase, ('', '2018-01-31 13:27:00', 'Full Moon'))

  # Query for the data in the table to make sure it's populated.
  cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM moon_phases')
  for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

**3. Run the pipelines queries**

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
import sqlite3
from typing import Iterable, List, Tuple, Dict

class SQLiteSelect(beam.DoFn):
  def __init__(self, database_file: str):
    self.database_file = database_file
    self.connection = None

  def setup(self):
    self.connection = sqlite3.connect(self.database_file)

  def process(self, query: Tuple[str, List[str]]) -> Iterable[Dict[str, str]]:
    table, columns = query
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT {','.join(columns)} FROM {table}")
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
      yield dict(zip(columns, row))

  def teardown(self):
    self.connection.close()

@beam.ptransform_fn 
@beam.typehints.with_output_types(Dict[str, str])
def SelectFromSQLite( 
    pbegin: beam.pvalue.PBegin,
    database_file: str,
    queries: List[Tuple[str, List[str]]],
) -> beam.PCollection[Dict[str, str]]:
  return (
      pbegin
      | 'Create None' >> beam.Create(queries)
      | 'SQLite SELECT' >> beam.ParDo(SQLiteSelect(database_file))
  )

queries = [
    # (table_name, [column1, column2, ...])
    ('moon_phases', ['phase_emoji', 'peak_datetime', 'phase']),
    ('moon_phases', ['phase_emoji', 'phase']),
]

options = PipelineOptions(flags=[], type_check_additional='all')
with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as pipeline:
  (
      pipeline
      | 'Read from SQLite' >> SelectFromSQLite(database_file, queries)
      | 'Print rows' >> beam.Map(print)
  )
```

**output**

```
{'phase_emoji': '', 'peak_datetime': '2017-12-03 15:47:00', 'phase': 'Full Moon'}
{'phase_emoji': '', 'peak_datetime': '2017-12-10 07:51:00', 'phase': 'Last Quarter'}
{'phase_emoji': '', 'peak_datetime': '2017-12-18 06:30:00', 'phase': 'New Moon'}
{'phase_emoji': '', 'peak_datetime': '2017-12-26 09:20:00', 'phase': 'First Quarter'}
{'phase_emoji': '', 'peak_datetime': '2018-01-02 02:24:00', 'phase': 'Full Moon'}
{'phase_emoji': '', 'peak_datetime': '2018-01-08 22:25:00', 'phase': 'Last Quarter'}
{'phase_emoji': '', 'peak_datetime': '2018-01-17 02:17:00', 'phase': 'New Moon'}
{'phase_emoji': '', 'peak_datetime': '2018-01-24 22:20:00', 'phase': 'First Quarter'}
{'phase_emoji': '', 'peak_datetime': '2018-01-31 13:27:00', 'phase': 'Full Moon'}
{'phase_emoji': '', 'phase': 'Full Moon'}
{'phase_emoji': '', 'phase': 'Last Quarter'}
{'phase_emoji': '', 'phase': 'New Moon'}
{'phase_emoji': '', 'phase': 'First Quarter'}
{'phase_emoji': '', 'phase': 'Full Moon'}
{'phase_emoji': '', 'phase': 'Last Quarter'}
{'phase_emoji': '', 'phase': 'New Moon'}
{'phase_emoji': '', 'phase': 'First Quarter'}
{'phase_emoji': '', 'phase': 'Full Moon'}
```

For more beam examples (either using java or python) the beam github project [example](https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/examples) node. Be advice that you might have to apply some adjustments as some are a bit deprecated or missing some imports.

As a final note, more on the testing aspect of your question. I think you can use `PAssert` to create [testing pipelines](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/pipelines/test-your-pipeline/) as described on its official documentation.

Comment: Hello Akhil Gupta, did this answer works for you?